# Get a list of all keys in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I want to get a list of all keys in a nested dictionary that contains lists and dictionaries.

I currently have this code, but it seems to be missing adding some keys to the list and also duplicate adds some keys.

```
keys_list = []
def get_keys(d_or_l, keys_list):
    if isinstance(d_or_l, dict):
        for k, v in iter(sorted(d_or_l.iteritems())):
            if isinstance(v, list):
                get_keys(v, keys_list)
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                get_keys(v, keys_list)
            else:
                keys_list.append(k)
    elif isinstance(d_or_l, list):
        for i in d_or_l:
            if isinstance(i, list):
                get_keys(i, keys_list)
            elif isinstance(i, dict):
                get_keys(i, keys_list)
    else:
        print "** Skipping item of type: {}".format(type(d_or_l))
    return keys_list
```

This just takes an empty list and populates it with the keys. d_or_l is a variable and takes the original dict to compare it against.

Comment: What do you want to do if there is same key in differerent directories ?

Comment: Doesn't matter if there are same keys.  I want this for doing a diff against the keys in different dicts for comparison purposes.  Taking out duplicate values wouldn't be good.

Answer (score 7):

This should do the job:

```
def get_keys(dl, keys_list):
    if isinstance(dl, dict):
        keys_list += dl.keys()
        map(lambda x: get_keys(x, keys_list), dl.values())
    elif isinstance(dl, list):
        map(lambda x: get_keys(x, keys_list), dl)
```

To avoid duplicates you can use set, e.g.:

```
keys_list = list( set( keys_list ) )
```

Example test case:

```
keys_list = []
d = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: [{7: {9: 1}}]}
get_keys(d, keys_list)
print keys_list
>>>> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: does this only work in py2?

Answer (score 5):

As it stands, your code ignores keys that lead to `list` or `dict` values.  Remove the `else` block in your first `for` loop, you want to add the key no matter what the value is.

```
keys_list = []
def get_keys(d_or_l, keys_list):
    if isinstance(d_or_l, dict):
        for k, v in iter(sorted(d_or_l.iteritems())):
            if isinstance(v, list):
                get_keys(v, keys_list)
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                get_keys(v, keys_list)
            keys_list.append(k)   #  Altered line
    elif isinstance(d_or_l, list):
        for i in d_or_l:
            if isinstance(i, list):
                get_keys(i, keys_list)
            elif isinstance(i, dict):
                get_keys(i, keys_list)
    else:
        print "** Skipping item of type: {}".format(type(d_or_l))
    return keys_list
```

`get_keys({1: 2, 3: 4, 5: [{7: {9: 1}}]}, keys_list)` returns `[1, 3, 9, 7, 5]`

To avoid duplication, you could use a [`set` datatype](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead of a `list`.

Comment: Doesn't work for dict with list and dict e.g. {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: [{7: {9: 1}}]}

Comment: @pm7 It works for me in my environment, I'll post the full code I used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
def get_nested_keys(d, keys):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            get_nested_keys(v, keys)
        else:
            keys.append(k)

keys_list = []
get_nested_keys(test_listing, keys_list)
print(keys_list)
```

If you want to know the hierarchy of the keys as well, you can modify the function like so:

```
def get_nested_keys(d, keys, prefix):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            get_nested_keys(v, keys, f'{prefix}:{k}')
        else:
            keys.append(f'{prefix}:{k}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would extend @pm007 answer by a python 2 & 3 friendly version:

```
def get_keys(dl, keys=None):
    keys = keys or []
    if isinstance(dl, dict):
        keys += dl.keys()
        _ = [get_keys(x, keys) for x in dl.values()]
    elif isinstance(dl, list):
        _ = [get_keys(x, keys) for x in dl]
    return list(set(keys))

d = {1: 2, 3: 4, 5: {7: {1: 1}}}
get_keys(d)
```

Furthermore this feels more convenient as you get a function that returns the desired keys instead of magically altering a list

Answer (score 0):

Updating @MackM's response to Python 3 as `dict.iteritems` has been deprecated (and I prefer to use f-strings over the `.format{}` styling):

```
keys_list = []
def get_keys(d_or_l, keys_list):
    if isinstance(d_or_l, dict):
        for k, v in iter(sorted(d_or_l.items())):  #  Altered line to update deprecated method
            if isinstance(v, list):
                get_keys(v, keys_list)
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                get_keys(v, keys_list)
            keys_list.append(k)   
    elif isinstance(d_or_l, list):
        for i in d_or_l:
            if isinstance(i, list):
                get_keys(i, keys_list)
            elif isinstance(i, dict):
                get_keys(i, keys_list)
    else:
        print(f'** Skipping item of type: {type(d_or_l)}')  #  Altered line to use f-strings
    return keys_list


unique_keys = list(set(get_keys(my_json_dict, keys_list)))  # Added line as example use case
```

Comment: how to handle getting hierachy? ie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75078908/python-get-all-keys-dot-separated-hierarchy-from-a-nested-dict-of-other-lists